# How to deploy Vue JS website to Ubuntu based VPS?

Tags: vue.js, ubuntu, nginx, server, vps

I have a VPS based on Linux Ubuntu.
I have two websites.
I have two domain names for both websites.
One website with domain trail-notes.tk is successfully deployed to VPS and is running on server without any ports in config file. Website is working fine. The problem is with the second website which I want to run on a specific port 4000 but on the same ip address of my server

When I did all the configurations and hit control-surface.ml it returns error "502 Bad Gateway"
[image: Bad gateway]

**How to deploy Vue applications/websites properly?**

Config file of first website trail-notes.tk for nginx:

```
    server {
    listen 80;
    server_name trail-notes.tk www.trail-notes.tk;
    root /home/kentforth/webapps/trail-notes/dist;
    index index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        root /home/kentforth/webapps/trail-notes/dist;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/vue-app-error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/vue-app-access.log;
}
```

What I already did:

1. Created Vue project
2. Created config file in vue project "vue.config.js"
3. Added port configuration to this file:

   module.exports = {
   devServer: {
   port: 4000
   }
   };
4. Pushed code to github
   5.Entered my VPS server
5. Cloned directory from github
6. Installed necessary dependencies:

   npm install --production
7. Installed Vue CLI for building project

   npm i @vue/cli-service
8. Built dist folder for production:

   npm run build
9. in directory /etc/nginx/sites-available/  created file control-surface-frontend.conf
10. Added configuration to that file:

    server {

    ```
    listen 80;
    server_name control-surface.ml www.control-surface.ml;

    root /home/kentforth/webapps/vue-test/dist;    


    index index.html;
    charset utf-8;


    location / {

        proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme; 

    }


    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    ```

    }
11. Activated symlink for that file:

    sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/control-surface-frontend.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/control-surface-frontend.conf
12. Tested symlink:

    sudo nginx -t

[image: success test symlink]

14. Restarted nginx:

    sudo systemctl restart nginx

15.Checked that nginx is running:
[image: nginx test]

**What did I do wrong?**

Answer (score 1):

I made wrong config file for nginx.
Here is my correct nginx config file and my website works fine:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name trail-notes.tk www.trail-notes.tk;
    root /home/kentforth/webapps/trail-notes/dist;
    index index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/vue-app-error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/vue-app-access.log;
}
```